# usage URL-maps fro HTTP loadbalancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, backend, url-mapping

I have two services running port 8080 and 8081 in GCP compute engine. I want to use a HTTP load balancer (url maps) to redirect the requests to appropriate ports.
I tried to add the backends(two backends one for 8080 and 8081). But I think it is a wrong approach since documenation says we need to use 80 or 443 since it is the traffic from load balancer to backend.
What is the solution for this.
How can I use a single load balancer for these two services which are running on same compute engine on different ports.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as you can read on the HTTP(S) Load Balancing documentation [1] you can read that:

> HTTP requests can be load balanced based on port 80 or port 8080. HTTPS requests can be load balanced on port 443.

As a workaround you can use it a HTTP(S) Load Balancing to redirect all request to the service running on port 8080 and configure the service to do the URL mapping to redirect certain path to the service on port 8081.

Here you can find more information regarding how to configure Apache [2] or Nginx [3] to redirect to the other service.

[1] https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

[2] https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

[3] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/